# Perl list all keys in hash with identical values

Tags: perl, hash, comparison, command-line-interface

If I have a colon-delimited file name FILE and I do:

```
cat FILE|perl -F: -lane 'my %hash = (); $hash{@F[0]} = @F[2]'
```

to assign the first and 3rd tokens as the key => value pairs for the hash..

1) Is that a sane way to assign key value pairs to a hash?

2) What is the simplest way to now find all keys with shared values and list them?

Assume FILE looks like:

```
 Mike:34:Apple:Male
 Don:23:Corn:Male
 Jared:12:Apple:Male
 Beth:56:Maize:Female
 Sam:34:Apple:Male
 David:34:Apple:Male
```

Desired Output: `Keys with value "Apple": Mike,Jared,David,Sam`

Comment: The actual trick in programming is to make it *correct* first, then, maybe, make it efficient, tricky, short, whatever.  Trying to start with a one-liner (even when looking tricky and smart) is probably not the correct solution for beginners; specifically when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example won't work as you want because the `-n` option puts a `while` loop around your one-line program, so the hash you declare is created and destoyed for every record in the file. You could get around that by not declaring the hash, and so making it a persistent package variable which will retain all values stored in it.

You can then write `push @{ $hash{$F[2]} }, $F[0]` but notice that it should be `$F[0]` etc. and not `@F[0]`, and I have used *push* to create a list of column 1 values for each column 3 value instead of just a list of one-to-one values relating each column 1 value with its column 3 value.

To clarify, your method produces a hash looking like this, which has to be searched to produce the display that you want.

```
(
  Beth  => "Maize",
  David => "Apple",
  Don   => "Corn",
  Jared => "Apple",
  Mike  => "Apple",
  Sam   => "Apple",
)
```

while mine creates this, which as you can see is pretty much already in the form you want.

```
(
  Apple => ["Mike", "Jared", "Sam", "David"],
  Corn  => ["Don"],
  Maize => ["Beth"],
)
```

But I think this problem is a bit too big to be solved with a one-line Perl program. The solution below expects the path to the input file as a command-line parameter, like this

```
> perl prog.pl colons.csv
```

but it will default to `myfile.csv` if no file is specified.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our @ARGV = 'myfile.csv' unless @ARGV;

my %data;
while (<>) {
  my @fields = split /:/;
  push @{ $data{$fields[2]} }, $fields[0];
}

while (my ($k, $v) = each %data) {
  next unless @$v > 1;
  printf qq{Keys with value "%s": %s\n}, $k, join ', ', @$v;
}
```

**output**

```
Keys with value "Apple": Mike, Jared, Sam, David
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a one liner, I just wanted to show that one liner to get feedback on the technique I used for populating the hash.  Is that a fair way to do it?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: I've added to my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you!  I will need to take a long look at this tonight when I have some quiet time to analyze.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: Please by all means ask if anything is unclear

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I finally am looking at this.  I need some clarification on this paragraph "You can then write push @{ $hash{$F[2]} }, $F[0] but notice that it should be $F[0] etc. and not @F[0], and I have used push to create a list of column 1 values for each column 3 value instead of just a list of one-to-one values relating each column 1 value with its column 3 value."

What exactly does referencing the array in scalar form do here?  How does this work exactly?  Where can I read more about this usage?

Comment: Also, does $v contain an array reference which is later dereferenced by @$v ?  You are using some techniques which are new to me which I clearly NEED to learn!

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';
my %data;
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split/:/;
    $data{$split[0]} = $split[2];
}

my $query = 'Apple';

print "Keys with value $query = ";
foreach my $name (keys %data){
    print "$name " if $data{$name} eq $query;
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the values, I want it to iterate though and find the matches, but I can modify this to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are used to hold list of values, so use an array.

```
perl -F: -lane'
   push @{ $h{$F[2]} }, $F[0];
   END {
      for my $fruit (keys %h) {
         next if @{ $h{$fruit} } < 2;
         print "$fruit: ", join(",", @{ $h{$fruit} });
      }
   }
' FILE
```

The `END` block is executed on exit. In it, we iterate over the keys of the hash. If the value of the current hash element is an array with only one element, it's skipped. Otherwise, we prints the key followed by contents of the array referenced by the hash element.

Comment: Can you explain this usage `push @{ $h{$F[2]} }, $F[0];` I think it was the missing piece for me.  Are you creating a hash of arrays?

Comment: You want an array for each value in column three, so it creates a hash of arrays.

Comment: Why does the assignment require $F[n] versus @F[n], what is the distinction in this context?

Comment: @Gregg Leventhal, `@F[$i]` is a weird way of writing `$F[$i]`. Why would just ask for a slice when you want an array element? Perl even warns you you're doing something weird.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, I was on my phone and un-upvoted your answer by accident. `:P`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
perl -F: -lane'
    push @{ $h{$F[2]} }, $F[0];
}{
    print "$_: ", join(",", @{ $h{$_} }) for grep { @{$h{$_}} > 1 } keys %h;
' file
```

We read each line and create hash of arrays using third column as key and first column as list of values for matching key. In the `END` block we iterate over our hash using `grep` and filter keys whose array count greater than 1 and print the key followed by array elements.

Comment: I think this is just what I was looking for, but I will need to play around with a it a bit when I have time to run it.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Sure, if you have any questions feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> **It doesn't have to be a one liner,**

Good. It's not going to be...

> **Is that a sane way to assign key value pairs to a hash?**

You're simply assigning the key value pairs as:

```
$hash{"key"} = "value";
```

Which is about as simple as it gets. There might be a way of doing it via [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). However, the main issue I see is what should happen if you have duplicate keys.

Let's say your file looks like this:

```
Mike:34:Apple:Male
Don:23:Corn:Male
Jared:12:Apple:Male
Beth:56:Maize:Female
Sam:34:Apple:Male
David:34:Apple:Male   # Note this entry is here twice!
David:35:Wheat:Male   # Note this entry is here twice!
```

Let's do a simple assignment loop:

```
my %hash;
while my $line ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $age, $category, $sex) = split /:/, $line;
    $hash{$name} = $category;
}
```

When you get to `$hash{David}`, it will first be set to `Apple`, but then you change the value to `Wheat`. There are four ways you can handle this:

1. Use whatever the last value is. No change in the loop.
2. Use the first value and ignore subsequent values. Simple enough to do.
3. If that happens, it's an error. Abort the program and report the error.
4. Keep all values.

This last one is the *most interesting* because it involves a reference to an array as the values for your hash:

```
my %hash;
while my $line ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $age, $category, $sex) = split /:/, $line;
    $hash{$name} = [] if not exists $hash{$name};   # I'm making this an array reference
    push @{ $hash{$name} }, $category;
}
```

Now, each value in my hash is a reference to an array:

```
my @values = @{ $hash{David} );   # The values of David...
print "David is in categories " . join ( ", ", @values ) . "\n";
```

This will print out `David is in categories Wheat, Apple`

> **What is the simplest way to now find all keys with shared values and list them?**

The easiest way is to create a *second* hash that's keyed by your value. In this hash, you will need to use an array reference. Let's assume no duplicate names for now:

```
my %hash;
my %indexed_hash;
while my $line ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $age, $category, $sex) = split /:/, $line;
    $hash{$name} = $category;

    my $indexed_hash{$category} = [] if not exist $indexed_hash{$category};
    push @{ $indexed_hash{$category} }, $name;
}
```

Now, if I want to find all the duplicates of `Apple`:

```
my @names = @{ $indexed_hash{Apple} };
print "The following are in 'Apple': " . join ( ", " @names ) . "\n";
```

Since we're getting into references, we could take things a step further and store all of your values of your file in your hash. Again, for simplicity, I am assuming that you will have one and only one entry per name:

```
my %hash;
while my $line ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $age, $category, $sex) = split /:/, $line;
    $hash{$name}->{AGE}      = $age;
    $hash{$name}->{CATEGORY} = $category;
    $hash{$name}->{SEX}      = $sex;
}

for my $name ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print "$name Information:\n";
    print "    Age: " . $hash{$name}->{AGE} . "\n";
    printf "Category: %s\n",  $hash{$name}->{CATEGORY};
    print "    Sex: @{[$hash{$name}->{SEX}]}\n\n";
}
```

That last two statements are easier ways of interpolating complex data structures into a string. The `printf` is fairly clear. The second `@{[...]}` is a neat little trick.

Comment: Thank you, I should have made clear it will be impossible for the first token to be duplicated elsewhere on the form, as this list will contain system usernames which cannot be reused.  I will reread your post and try to internalize everything now.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

If you `reverse` the hash into a list of value => key pairs then use List::Util's `pairs()` against the list, you can transform the hash into a hash of values => key arrayrefs. i.e. `( foo => [ 'bar', 'baz' ] )`, `grep {@{$hash{$_}} > 1} keys %hash`, and print the results.

Comment: I tried something messy involving nested loops pushing values onto a new hash/array, but as Mr. Castanza said about Festivus: "There has GOT to be a better way!"  Thanks, very nice solution.  I don't use modules nearly as much as I should.

Comment: Also, what about the way I am assigning to the hash using the default arrays, is that reasonable?

Comment: It's fine for an audience that understands perl command lines. I wouldn't do this whole thing as a oneliner, but as a script that takes a filename as an argument and reads it, probably with File::Slurp to be lazy. Then people using the script can run `script.pl inputfile.txt` and be done with it.

Comment: ... or you could just build the hash the way you want it in the first place.